# How to Align Title, Input Box & Ionic Icon Side by Side in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-3

So far, I have been able to figure out how to left align Title and right align icon, but the problem is with input box in the center which I am not able to figure out.

Expected output Image is given below.

[image: Ionic 3 Expected Output Image]

My Home Page Code:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>    
      <ion-title text-center>Page Title</ion-title>

    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only>          
          <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>

  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>       

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed it on my own!

Home HTML file

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Title
      <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only>          
          <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>

  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>


</ion-content>
```

Variable.scss file

```
$text-input-md-margin-top: 0px; 
$text-input-md-margin-bottom: 0px;
$text-input-md-margin-start: 0px;   
$text-input-md-margin-end: 0px;
```

Home.scss file

```
ion-input
{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;      
    display: inline;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
}

.text-input-md
{
    width: 60%;    
}
```